# IE 10 not loading resources file

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, css, browser-cache

I am building a web page using HTML5, css3 and Jquery. when I try to view that page in IE x it is not showing page, when I checked in Developer tool, I got following,  [image]

I tried clearing cache, changing security level. I am loading my css from local folder and it is linked properly because I can view page complete in other browsers. I googled the same but did not get any clue cause in HTML and CSS tab I can see my code but IE x not showing page. Any Idea why this is so[image]

My Head<>

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link href="Content/css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="Content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Show the code used to load the CSS

Comment: @Cfreak: please check the question again, updated it

Answer (score 0):

Testing against the filesystem is generally a bad idea, particularly in modern versions of IE which use multiple different isolation technologies that impact loading of local files.

e.g.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/06/20/loading-local-files-in-enhanced-protected-mode-in-internet-explorer-10.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/08/12/internet-explorer-9.0.2-update-changes-file-protocol-and-cookie-naming.aspx

Instead, use a lightweight web server (IIS Express, Cassini, Apache, node.js, etc) to serve your content over HTTP and verify that the problem goes away.

You didn't mention which version of Windows you're using?